# Using SSLKEYLOGFILE and RSA key lists but still encrypted tls in wireshark. what can i do next?

Tags: encryption

I tried to decrypt tls in wireshark, but it does not work properly. I created a file using the SSLKEYLOGFILE environment variable, registered it in Wireshark's Pre-Master-Secret, and ran it in Wireshark, but it was not decrypted. When I searched, it told me to register the pem file, so I found the pem file of the server I wanted to enter and ran the rsa key list. It's registered inside. However, decryption is still not possible. What should I do in this case?

When I set the IP in the app and run it, sometimes I can't log in, so I want to know for sure whether this is a server problem or an app problem.